# custom class, x in list / x not in list behaving oddly

Tags: python, list, contains, equality

I have a nested structure of classes

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, goal=False, skip=False):
        self.CELLS = []

        self.deck = copy.deepcopy(deck)
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

        for row in xrange(1,5):
            for column in xrange(1, 14):
                card = self.deck.pop(0)
                cell = Cell(row, column, card)
                self.CELLS.append(cell) 

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for cell1, cell2 in zip(self.CELLS, other.CELLS):
            if cell1 != cell2:
                return False
        return True
        # return self.CELLS == other.CELLS

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

class Row:
    def __init__(self, cells):
        self.cells = cells

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.cells == other.cells

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

class Cell:
    def __init__(self, row, column, card):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.index = ROW_COL_TO_INDEX(row, column) # 0 ~ 51
        self.card = card

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other is not None:
            return all([self.row == other.row,
                       self.column == other.column,
                       self.index == other.index,
                       self.card == other.card])
        return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suite):
        self.value = value
        self.suite = suite

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.value == other.value and self.suite == other.suite
        except AttributeError:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

deck = []
for suite in ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']:
    for n in xrange(1,14):
        if n == 1:
            deck.append("SPACE")
        else:
            deck.append(Card(value=n, suite=suite))
```

Board has rows, rows have cells, cells have cards.

I'm trying to solve a card game using DFS/BFS, I'm going through the moves until I find the solution or get that there's no solution for the problem.

The DFS algorith has a list called `visited`

Before adding new entries to the stack I check if the entry is `not in` the already `visited`. Like so

```
def depth_first_search(start):
    visited, stack = [], [start]

    while stack:
        move = stack.pop()
        if win(move):
            return visited
        if move not in visited:
            visited.append(move)
            stack.extend(get_children(move))  # add new entries

    raise ValueError("No solution found")
```

But it still gives me repeated entries to process, making it impossible to find a solution or state that there's no solution.

ex:

```
Board 1
__  2H  3H  4H  5H  6H  7H  8H  9H  10H JH  QH  KH  
__  2S  3S  4S  5S  6S  7S  8S  9S  10S JS  QS  KS  
__  2C  3C  4C  5C  6C  7C  8C  9C  10C JC  QC  KC  
__  2D  3D  4D  5D  6D  7D  8D  9D  10D JD  QD  KD


.
.
.

Board 315
__  2H  3H  4H  5H  6H  7H  8H  9H  10H JH  QH  KH  
__  2S  3S  4S  5S  6S  7S  8S  9S  10S JS  QS  KS  
__  2C  3C  4C  5C  6C  7C  8C  9C  10C JC  QC  KC  
__  2D  3D  4D  5D  6D  7D  8D  9D  10D JD  QD  KD
```

I implemented `__eq__` and `__ne__` in the classes, but it still doesn't work.

What's going on?

Comment: You can't yadda yadda yadda your class definitions when it's almost certainly something in the class definition.

Comment: you never define `vertex`, what is it supposed to be?

Comment: Can you show your definitions for `__eq__` and `__ne__`

Comment: Can you show us an MCVE for the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RNar, O sorry, I was chaging the variable name when posting.

Comment: @MartinBonner, If I could reproduce it in small scale, I would be able to fix it myself. I have no clue what part of the code is not working.